# SpringSource Tool Suite (STS): How to run server and Java project through the IDE?

Tags: sts-springsourcetoolsuite, springsource

I'm using the latest version of SpringSource Tool Suite (STS).  I have set up a Java project.  My code has an Ant build file that packages a WAR.  I have Tomcat 6.0.24 installed locally on my Mac 10.6.3.  Can someone point me to how I deploy my project onto the server from the IDE and as such, set up debugging with breakpoints?

Thanks, - Dave

Comment: Were you able to solve this problem? I'm also trying to do things this way.

Answer (score 9):

Here is what you need to do:

1. Open up the servers view inside of STS.
2. Create a new Tomcat instance, and point it to your locally installed Tomcat.  (Alternatively, you can use the pre-installed tcServer instance, which is essentially Tomcat with a few extra things like Spring Insight).
3. Right-click on your project and select Configure -> Convert to Faceted Form...
4. In the dialog that comes up, choose *Dynamic Web Module*
5. Now, you should be able to drag and drop your project onto the server instance.
6. After that, right-click on the server instance and select "Debug"

You can find more detailed instructions here:
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-eclipse-tomcat/index.html